# WorldSense and Safety Fog

Tags: google-vr

I am developing a roomscale app, which I'm planning to deploy on the Mirage Solo because of the 6DOF. But because of the Safety Fog feature of WorldSense, there is no use for me if that fog cannot be disabled. Since I am targeting this to be a location-specific app for a research I was wondering if deploying it as a development version (which supposedly allow this feature to be turned off, anyone can confirm?) could allow me to have a working area of maximum 20 by 20 metres... is that possible on a daydream 6DOF device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn this off in the developer settings.

First enable developer ( About -> Build -> Click 7 times ) then come back out to the Daydream settings menu -> VR Settings -> Developer Options and you'll see a checkbox for the UI Safety feature which you can turn off.